# How would you access sub-dictionaries in a nested json response dictionary when the primary (first level) dictionary key varies?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a json response like this:

```
{'3830': {'success': True, 'data': {'categories': [{'id': 2, 'description': 'Single-player'}, {etc...
```

I would like to access the sub-dictionary `categories`, however the primary dictionary key, `3830` in the above example, varies. The json response is the result of `requests.get` iterating through a list, thus the primary dictionary key changes with each response. I can't figure out how to set a variable within the function that contains the contents of `categories`.

I tried:

```
data = await response.json()
mp_data = data['3830']['data']['categories']
```

which of course worked for the first iteration as the 3830 matched, but failed with KeyError on following iterations. Also tried using a variable for first level like `['*']` and `[*]` but this didn't work either.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just do `for key in data: mp_data = key["data"]["categories"]`?

Comment: This may prove helpful as I refactor my code. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always the first key that you want to access, use

```
first_key = list(data.keys())[0]
```

To get the first key and then use this to access the lower level data

```
mp_data = data[first_key]['data']['categories']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. This makes sense! However, I get the following error: File "main.py", line 50, in get_games
    first_key = data.keys()[0]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I've updated the code above. Convert it to a list first, or use next to get the first object.

Comment: @JaredRobertson, you're using Python3 which returns a view rather than list for `dict.keys()`. Materialize the view with a cast to list.

Comment: @scotty3785 thank you, it seems that did the trick. I assume this technique could also apply to the second key if it also varied, which will prove very helpful if so. Much appreciated!

Comment: `next` won't work like that, dict-keys objects are *not an iterator*. Note, in *neither* case do you really need `.keys()`, you can jsut use `list(data)[0]` or `next(iter(data))`